# Can you update meta and Open Graph tags with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, meta-tags

Is it possible to update Open Graph and meta tags with Javascript, or will search engines and Facebook ignore Javascript calls to update these tags?

Comment: Search engines will ignore javascript to alter the meta values. They'll be used as in the html source literally.

Comment: I was messing around with this, blindly hoping it'd work, but it can't for all the reasons mentioned. You can only do it by coding your OG tags in your code behind (assuming you're using some kind of .net application) and place them in your head tags with this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding OG tags, FB sees your page the same way that search engine robots do, so changing them with Javascript will be invisible to the FB linter as it won't even run any JS on your page.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but I hoped there was another solution. Darn. Thanks anyway.